# how to print the dynamic array books * arr

Tags: c, struct

how to print the dynamic array books * arr and do i have to add something more
how to print the dynamic array books * arr
how to print the dynamic array books * arr

```
  typedef struct Book
    {
        char name[32];
        char genre[32];
        char author[32];
        int numOfPages;
        int price;
    }books;


struct Library
{
    char name[32];
    books* arr;
        int numOfBooks; 
    };

    int main()
    {

    struct Book book1;

    strcpy(book1.name,"Learn C.");
    strcpy(book1.genre,"Fantastic");
    strcpy(book1.author,"Dont know who");
    kniga1.numOfPages=666;
    kniga1.price=100;

    books* arr=(books*)malloc(sizeof(books));

    struct Library library1;
    strcpy(library1.name,"Biblioteka1");
    library1.numOfBooks=1;
```

Comment: You had to copy the same thing multiple times in order to get around the system "too much code" warnig, didn't you? Please rethink.

Comment: ohh i've accidently put it twice,even didnt know for that "too much code "warning

Comment: Please demonstrate more of your own effort and elaborate your own thinking. Applying consistent indentation might be helpful on the way to providing a decent [mre].

Comment: You put it thrice. Delete two of them and you will see.

Comment: I think the question is asked clear enough,even if there is too much code,thats why i did it because i cant add nothing more to ease the things

Comment: thats not the problem @HelpmebuyLambo, the problem here is that you just create the structs, put some code and then asked how you can iterate over books *arr
whats your starting point to do that?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `kniga1.numOfPages=666;
    kniga1.price=100;`  What is `kniga1` ?  It is not define anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `books* arr=(books*)malloc(sizeof(books));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: The struct library has a pointer to a struct books, however, when filling in the struct library instance, the code fails to set the field: `arr` to point to the instance of `struct books`

Comment: the posted code only creates a single instance of the struct books, not an array of struct books.   You have not shown your attempt to print that single instance, so how are we to comment upon your efforts.

Comment: Note: the field: `int numOfBooks`   This variable will never be less than 0 so it should be a 'unsigned' type, suggest `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question: *how to print the dynamic array books * ar*...

assuming you have created such an array (which the posted code has not done.

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < library1.numOfBooks; i++ )
{
    printf( "%s  ", library1.arr[i]->name );
    printf( "%s  ", library1.arr[i]->genre );
    printf( "%s  ", library1.arr[i]->author );
    printf( "%d  ", library1.arr[i]->numOfPages );
    printf( "%d\n", library1.arr[i]->price );
}
```